# using codebird.php to display twitter list statuses

Tags: php, javascript, twitter

So I went through this tutorial and set up a twitter widget that uses codebird.php and javascript to display a list of a twitter user's statuses, or a search term:

[Easiest Way to Retrieve Twitter Timeline and Hashtags (Twitter OAuth API 1.1)](http://www.queness.com/post/14004/easiest-way-to-retrieve-twitter-timeline-and-hashtags-twitter-oauth-api-11)

What I want to do now is edit it so that it will display statuses of a twitter list, such as:

https://twitter.com/13news/norfolk

I think I need to switch the "search" option below to "list"

```
 search: '%23heroes2013', //leave this blank if you want to show user's tweet
user: 'quenesstestacc', //username
```

and also edit this section of code to take lists instead of search terms, but I'm not sure how.

```
 // different JSON request {hash|user}
    if (JQTWEET.search) {
      request = {
          q: JQTWEET.search,
          count: JQTWEET.numTweets,
          api: 'search_tweets'
      }
    } else {
      request = {
          q: JQTWEET.user,
          count: JQTWEET.numTweets,
          api: 'statuses_userTimeline'
      }
    }
```

Codebird's Readme file explains mapping Twitter API methods to Codebird's function calls like this:

> For each slash in a Twitter API method, use an underscore in the Codebird function.
>
> Example: statuses/update maps to Codebird::statuses_update().
>
> For each underscore in a Twitter API method, use camelCase in the Codebird function.
>
> Example: statuses/home_timeline maps to Codebird::statuses_homeTimeline().
>
> For each parameter template in method, use UPPERCASE in the Codebird function. Also don’t forget to include the parameter in your parameter list.
>
> Examples:
>
> statuses/show/:id maps to Codebird::statuses_show_ID('id=12345').
> users/profile_image/:screen_name maps to >Codebird::users_profileImage_SCREEN_NAME('screen_name=mynetx').<

However, I can't find how to map something like this:

> lists/statuses.json?slug=teams&owner_screen_name=MLS&count=1

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

For the API call you mentioned, mapping should be as easy as this:

```
<?php
$cb->lists_statuses('slug=teams&owner_screen_name=MLS&count=1');
?>
```

Does it work?